# Data not reaching API Controller REQUEST failure

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an application where UI is built by Angular js and backend on Asp.net mvc. On button click i am calling angular service which is passing json object to asp.net API controller instead of normal mvc controller. This is because API controller has to generate excel file and return HttpResponseMessage. Now when the call goes from angular service to API controller data is not reaching and it shows as failed request. In my route config i have url defined as "{controller}/{action}/{id}".Also calls to normal controllers is happening fine. Do i need to add url for api controller so service call reaches the api controller. Also normal mvc controller and api controller are in same folder. Also for info I am running app in https with various settings on IIS in local dev. Below is the code for angular service and mvc api controller.

```
Service: 
ServiceSlarDetails.prototype.GetSlarExcelFile = function () {
            var link, params;
            //link = baseUrl + '/SLAR/GetSlarExcelFile';
            link = baseUrl + '/File/GetSlarExcelFile';
            params = "'" + JSON.stringify(this.object) + "'";
            return $http({
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
                method: 'POST',
                url: link,
                responseType: "arraybuffer",
                data: params
            }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
                return response.data;
            }).catch(function onError(data, status, headers, config) {
                return NewAlert.show('Oops!', 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again.', 'error');
            });
        };


 API CONTROLLER: 
   public class FileController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSlarExcelFile([FromBody] string ExcelTable)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        object obj = null;
        HttpResponseMessage FailReturn = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        try
        {
            var data = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ExcelTable, (typeof(DataTable)));
            data.TableName = "Slar";
            if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFiles");
                //if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                //{
                //    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                //}
                using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                {

                    wb.Worksheets.Add(data);

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    {

                        //wb.SaveAs(path + "/" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".xlsx");
                        wb.SaveAs(ms);



                        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer());
                        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Invoices.xlsx";
                        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

                        result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = ms.Length;
                        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    }
                }
            }

            // obj = new { resp = data, error = "" };

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Logger.Error(ex.Message);
            //obj = new { resp = "", error = ex.Message.ToString() };
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted calling this from postman? What URL are you calling? localhost/FileController/GetSlarExcelFile? Are you sure you are doing an HTTP POST?

Comment: localhost/File/GetSlarExcelFile